# Money gem converting variable of currency code to lower case

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, money-rails

I am using the money gem in rails to perform some currency conversion.

I'd like to dynamically set the conversion rate so that I can use it in a script.

```
currency_code = ":SEK"

conversion_rate = @bank.get_rate(:USD, currency_code).to_f
```

I get this error:

```
Money::Currency::UnknownCurrency: Unknown currency ':sek'
```

Which means it's converting the variable to lower case. If I explicitly put in `:SEK` I don't have any issues.

I've even tried playing around with this:

```
cb = "SEK"

conversion_rate = @bank.get_rate(:USD, ":#{cb}").to_f
```

And

```
cc = ":SEK"

conversion_rate = @bank.get_rate(:USD, cc.upcase).to_f
```

However I get the same error.

Any ideas?

Comment: why can't you use || currency_code = :SEK || I believe the fact that are passing in a string instead of a symbol is the source of your problem.

Comment: Wow that worked exactly! Silly me.. Thanks mate! Do you want to make it an answer and I'll accept?

Comment: Hey @JeffPrice how could this value be stored in a column? Or do you know how I could create that dynamically based on : + SEK

Comment: nevermind got it.. .to_sym!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bnussey,

I looks like you are passing in your currency as a string instead of a symbol. Try this instead:

```
currency_code = :SEK
```

If you need to store a string in the database, Ruby can easily convert it to a symbol.

```
currency = "SEK"
currency_code = currency.to_sym
=> :SEK
```